# Flink StreamExcutionEnvironment vs ExecutionEnvironment

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading about Flink Batch Mode for word count at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/dataset/overview/

It looks to me:

1. For batch, I need `ExecutionEnvironment`, like `val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment`
2. For stream, I need `StreamExecutionEnvironmetn`, like `val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment`

I have been alreays confused about these execution environment. Since Flink is said to be unified batch and processing framework, I have thought that the execution environment creation should be only `one`, eg:

`val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment("streaming mode ")` for stream,  and
`val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment("batch mode")`,

I would ask why, the execution environments are separated. I have always been confused when it comes to execution environments,including the table execution environments. I think I didn't grasp the design consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APIs are a bit confusing right now. But the community is working on removing this legacy and unifying the APIs.

In the early days, Flink started as a batch processor with a streaming runtime under the hood. So the DataSet API with `ExecutionEnvironment` was exposed for batch processing.

([The DataSet API is reaching end-of-life and will be deprecated soon](https://flink.apache.org/roadmap.html#feature-radar).)

Later, Flink exposed the streaming runtime via DataStream API with `StreamExecutionEnvironment`. This is one of the main APIs today. Its vision is to work on unbounded **and** bounded streams. Since batch processing is only a special case of streaming, it can be categorized under bounded stream processing.

The Table API with `TableEnvironment` was the first API that fully unified the both worlds in one API. The DataStream API is currently receiving a [batch execution mode](https://flink.apache.org/2021/03/11/batch-execution-mode.html) for faster processing of bounded streams. All of that is already present in Table API.